# Is it expected to face slowness while while typing, in a SSH over Tor connection?

Tags: ssh

I can connect to my web hosting, with ease.

Although, every single character I type into CLI seems to have a *0.5s* delay, before actually getting input.

Is it expected behavior, since I'm using Tor or what?

This is my SSH config file:

```
Host *.onion
        ProxyCommand nc -x localhost:9050 %h %p

Host <domain>
        User <user>
        Hostname <hostname>
        Port 22
```

#### Other Details

- I'm using [dnscrypt-proxy](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy);

  - whitelisted servers are located across the ocean;
  - does it matter, at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected due to the additional latency caused by sending your traffic through 6 relays around the world. Depending on what circuit you get, sometimes the latency will be smaller, and sometimes larger.

If you don't need anonymity for your onion service, you may want to look into setting up a single-hop onion service (see `HiddenServiceSingleHopMode` and `HiddenServiceNonAnonymousMode` in the tor man page). This effectively will cause your circuit to use 4 relays instead of 6, reducing latency.